# GridView не обновляется после редактирования с помощью команд SqlDataSource

Tags: c#, sql, веб-программирование, asp.net, asp.net-webforms

делаю веб-приложение, в общем есть гридвью и к нему привязан источник данных из БД SQL. Кнопка командная которая "Правка" позволяет вносить изменения, только вот при нажатии кнопки "Обновить" изменения сбрасываются и из режима редактирования гридвью не выходит.

Вот, например, нажимаю "Правка" у последней строки
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тут изменения внесла и нажимаю "Обновить"
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

...а изменения после нажатия сбрасываются и гридвью не обновляется, дак еще и не выходит из режима редактирования
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прикрепляю хтмл-евский код

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="AdressForm.aspx.cs" Inherits="ПРАКТИКА_2_КУРС_ВЕБ_формс.AdressForm" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            Адреса пациентов</div>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Код адреса"  DataSourceID="AdressSource" AllowPaging="True" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#336666" BorderStyle="Double" BorderWidth="3px" CellPadding="4" GridLines="Horizontal" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound" OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField ShowInsertButton="true" ShowEditButton="true" ShowDeleteButton="True" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Код адреса" HeaderText="Код адреса" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Код адреса" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Номер амбулаторной карты" HeaderText="Номер амбулаторной карты" SortExpression="Номер амбулаторной карты" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="город" HeaderText="Город" SortExpression="город" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="улица" HeaderText="Улица" SortExpression="улица" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Дом" HeaderText="Дом" SortExpression="Дом" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Квартира/комната" HeaderText="Квартира/комната" SortExpression="Квартира/комната" />
            </Columns>
            <FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#336666" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#336666" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#339966" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F7F7F7" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#487575" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E5E5E5" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#275353" />
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="AdressSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:myConnection %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Адрес пациента]" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [dbo].[Адрес пациента] WHERE [Код адреса]=@Кодадреса;" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [dbo].[Адрес пациента]
           ([Номер амбулаторной карты]
      ,[город]
      ,[улица]
      ,[Дом]
      ,[Квартира/комната])
     VALUES
           (@Номерамбулаторнойкарты
           ,@Город
           ,@Улица
           ,@Дом
           ,@Квартиракомната)" OnLoad="AdressSource_Load" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [dbo].[Адрес пациента]
   SET [Номер амбулаторной карты] = @Номерамбулаторнойкарты
      ,[город] = @Город
      ,[улица] = @Улица
      ,[Дом] = @Дом
      ,[Квартира/комната] = @Квартиракомната
 WHERE [Код адреса]=@Кодадреса">
            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="Номерамбулаторнойкарты" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Город" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Улица" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Дом" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Квартиракомната" />
            </InsertParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="Номерамбулаторнойкарты" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Город" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Улица" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Дом" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Квартиракомната" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Кодадреса" />
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GridView1" Name="Номерамбулаторнойкарты" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />       

            </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Обновить" OnClick="Button2_Click" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" style="margin-left: 28px" Text="Button" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Код обработчиков событий тоже прикреплю:

```
    protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
    }

    protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        BindData();
    }
    protected void GridView1_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
        BindData();
    }
    private void BindData()
    {
        GridView1.DataSourceID = null;
        GridView1.DataSource = AdressSource;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

В чем может быть дело? Всем заранее спасибо за ответы!!!

Comment: зачем все эти подписки на `GridView1_RowUpdating` и `GridView1_RowEditing` ?

Comment: Я когда то очень давно писал [статью по GridView](https://tym32167.blogspot.com/2012/01/aspnet-gridview.html), я сйекчас уже не помню ничего, но может вам она чем то поможет.

Comment: Вам по сути вообще не нужны эти события и обновлять биндинг тоже нет надобности. Вот [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource?view=netframework-4.8) есть ещё примеры.

Comment: без подписок кидает исключения что события не обработаны, если их оставлять пустыми то все равно такой же результат (не сохраняет изменения)

Comment: вы пробовали пример из документации? Там вообще кода не нужно, только разметка.